# ASP.NET Authentication Questions

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I use ASP.NET and ASP.NET Authentication.

I have a website with structure like:

```
ROOT
   - CMS
     - AdminCms
     - web.conf*
   - FORUM
     - AdminForum
      - web.conf*
   - web.conf ***
```

Now in `web.conf ***` I use for CMS LOGIN PAGE

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Cms/AdminCms/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

My Questions:

- How can I have another DEFAULT LOGIN PAGE for another folder? (if the user use for example FORUM).
- Would be possible insert in web.conf* another

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Forum/AdminForum/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need two separate login pages? You can just redirect to the right page (CMS or forum) after a successful login, depending on where the user came from.

Comment: yes sounds good. How to do it? could you send me a link of example? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my comment earlier - Forms authentication allows redirecting a user to different pages after a successful login. To enable this, the forms authentication keeps track of the original page a user came from in the ReturnUL request parameter to the login page.

In your case you could do something like this in the codebehind of your login page after a successful login:

```
string originalTarget = Request.Params["ReturnUrl"];

if(originalTarget  != null)
{
   if(originalTarget.Contains(@"/FORUM/")
      Response.Redirect(someForumURL);
   else
      Response.Redirect(someCMSURL);
}
```

Edit: Here also a link to an article - [Forms Authentication - Redirecting users to a Page other than Default.aspx](http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2005/04/25/37612.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you mark both the folders, CMD and Forum as an application in IIS, you can easily do this since both of them will be a separate application domain.